# Setting expiry using koa-jwt

Tags: node.js, jwt, koa

I'm attempting to use the json web token [koa-jwt middleware](https://github.com/koajs/jwt) for a koa-based node app I'm writing. I'd like to set the expiry of the web-token's payload and I've noticed that using the standard implementation produces an expiry date in the payload that is two months later. This implementation looks like the following:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var jwt = require('koa-jwt');

var app = koa();

...

// This is the jwt line in question...
app.use(jwt({ secret: 'shared-secret' }));

...
```

What I'd like to do is control this so that I can set it to be 1 week, 1 day, 15 minutes, whatever. I've tried a number of variations such as:

```
app.use(jwt({ secret: 'shared-secret', exp: 30 }));
app.use(jwt({ secret: 'shared-secret', expires: 30 }));
```

...and many others, but so far nothing has worked and the documentation is very light in this regard. Any insights as to how this is done would be appreciated.

**Feb 26 Update**
Thanks to clemkoa I found my answer - turns out I was doing exactly what I needed to with the "exp" attribute the whole time. During login a successful authentication of user returns this:

```
ctx.body = {success: true, token: user.generateJWT()};
```

Where user.generateJWT() is a function call in the User Mongoose schema. The function looks like this:

```
UserSchema.methods.generateJWT = function() {
  // set jwt expiration
  var today = new Date();
  var exp = new Date(today);
  exp.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);

  return jwt.sign({
    _id: this._id,
    username: this.username,
    exp: parseInt(exp.getTime() / 1000)
  }, config.jwtSecret);
};
```

Note the inclusion of the "exp" attribute. That is the line in question.

Comment: Have you tried 'expiresIn' ? I don't know koa-jwt but it seems inspired from jsonwebtoken, which uses expiresIn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/koajs/jwt/blob/d3b169b85571034a73d0343ca5f5fd0deab0d452/test.js

Line 92, they use the 'exp' attribute, but at the time of .sign(), not when defining jwt

Comment: Thanks clemkoa - as it turns out I was setting the "exp" attribute the whole time but was simply too dim to realize it. Now that I understand where this is being done I can successfully control the expiry to what ever I need. See my modified question above for details on where/how this was done.